# Set model property to boolean in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am just starting to learn a bit about the entity framework and don't have much experience with ORM's.

In my little app I have one table, this sql server table has several columns including a PrimaryKey (int) a Name (string) and a Flag (tinyint).

When I imported this table into it automatically assigned the Flags' datatype as a byte. This is fine, but the Flag should really be a boolean, so I

1. Clicked on the Mapping Details
2. Selected my Flag property
3. Changed the Type from Byte to Boolean
4. Rebuilt the application

I then got this error:

> Error 2019: Member Mapping specified
>   is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Boolean[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]'
>   of member 'MyFlag' in type
>   'MyModel.MyItem' is not compatible
>   with
>   'SqlServer.tinyint[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]'
>   of member 'MyFlag' in type
>   'MyModel.Store.MyItem'.

Is there a way to have

```
MyItem item = new MyItem();
item.Flag = true;
```

and have Flag save to 1 in the database?

Comment: Why would you ever need that instead of a bool?

Comment: @JonasStensved the problem was that the database table that I was using had the incorrect datatype in it. Once I changed the table to use a `bit` instead of a `byte` then everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could change the datatype of `MyFlag` to **`bit`** in the database.

Comment: Thanks, bit is certainly the correct datatype to use in this situation

Comment: And what if I'm using a View?

Comment: @Bruno Views should be used the same as tables if you are using Code First (mapping from the DB to the Model) if you are using an EDMX try [this article](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/)

Comment: Spent a long time trying to address this until I found this post. DB first MySQL Linq EF6. I changed all tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE to BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0' and for the moment life is blissful. This was the error I was previously seeing "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

Answer (score 3):

I think for the `tinyint` you will have to make a partial class and use a separate field that appropriately read/writes to that field.  However the framework will correctly interpret `bit` fields as `boolean`.

You could try something like below as the partial..

```
public partial class MyItem
{
    public bool FlagBool
    {
        get { return Flag == 1; }
        set { Flag = value ? 1 : 0; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right, I should have used bit instead.

Comment: No problem, been through it before.