# Member Mapping specified is not valid.Error in ADO.net Entity Framework when add new column in database?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, nopcommerce

I am very new to `ADo.net entity` framework and i am getting the following error

```
 The type 'Edm.Byte' of the member 'IsActive' in the conceptual side type 
 NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Data.Language' does not match with the type 
 System.Boolean' of the member 'IsActive' on the object side type   NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Directory.Language'.
```

as far i understand that there is some missing to relating the data type of ***edm*** and ***object***

but i made a column in database table which is bit type and in `langauge.cs` i declare the property of

```
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

any details needed i can post here

EDIT :

as i google around i found this question on stackoverflow

[et-model-property-to-boolean-in-entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446054/set-model-property-to-boolean-in-entity-framework) which is changing the Byte to Boolean for mapping tinyint

but in my case i have in database is also the bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you have an .edmx-file you can modify. Open it in an XML-editor and search for the `<edmx:ConceptualModels>`-element. This should contain the definition of your entities, look for the `<EntityType Name="Language">`-element, which should declare something like this:

```
<Property Name="IsActive" Type="Byte" Nullable="false" />
```

Change the `Type`-attribute to `Boolean`.

I'm pretty sure that you could also do this in the designer, but if you don't have direct access to the .edmx let me know and we figure something out.

Comment: @Tihon thanks buddy its works . i have permission on .edmx file so right click on field and change its datatype to boolean

Comment: Does updating a EDMX Doesnt Fix this ?