# How do I switch column values from 0 to 1 and vice versa using the update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table `Table1` as follows

```
col1 col2
---- ----
 A    1
 B    1
 C    1
 D    0
 E    0
 F    0
```

I  want the result table should be as follows (by using `Update` statement)

```
col1 col2
---- ----
 A    0
 B    0
 C    0
 D    1
 E    1
 F    1
```

Comment: Depending on the second column value if it is 0 then it should update with 1 and if it is 1 then it should update with 0. I tried with update and case but it was not working.

Answer (score 37):

***Script 1***: [Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fba8a/1)

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET col2 = (CASE col2 WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
```

***Script 2***: If the values are always 0 or 1, you could use the *Bitwise Exclusive OR operator*. [Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a7db/2)

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET col2 = (col2 ^ 1);
```

Comment: In a contrived test, against an enormous table, your Script 2 was just a hair faster than my try.  Not sure we can improve on that one. Nice work!

Comment: not what OP wanted, but in case anyone googles this. This also works when checking strings: UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET col1 = (CASE col1 WHEN 'A' THEN 'B' WHEN 'B' THEN 'A' ELSE col1 END);

Answer (score 22):

Since you mentioned you are using INTs, how about:

```
update dbo.Table1 set col2 = 1 - col2;
```

Comment: this is simple and brilliant

Answer (score 15):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but this should work:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET col2 = CASE col2 WHEN 0 THEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE col2 END
```

Comment: Excellent... It is working fine. Thanks a lot for your quick help. :)

Answer (score 10):

If you are using proper boolean (BIT) on SQL Server, you can use this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ed3c/1

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET col2 = ~col2;
```

Comment: Just a nit-pick, BIT is not the same as BOOLEAN. There is no BOOLEAN type in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server has no boolean, that's why this doesn't work `SELECT * FROM Assets WHERE IsInsured`. SQL Server's BIT is not a first-class boolean as other database though (e.g. PostgreSQL). SQL Server's boolean is non-existent as it was on Fortran. BIT is introduced by SQL Server team for boolean purposes. But for all intents and purposes, SQL Server's BIT is in every bit a boolean. Entity Framework and many ORMs honor this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446054/set-model-property-to-boolean-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 2):

Very Simple query

```
update table set col= (col-1)* -1;
```

Explanation:

- Case of 0:

  ```
  update table set col= (0-1)* -1; // return 1;
  ```
- Case of 1 :

  ```
  update table set col= (1-1)* -1; // return 0;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :

```
UPDATE table SET col = 1-col
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.