# Conversion issue in c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I am getting an error like

> The 'IsActive' property on 'City' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'.

The value of the `IsActive` column I am getting is `1`.

```
public List<City> AutoCompleteCity(string serachParameter)
{
    var parameter = new SqlParameter("@SERACH", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    parameter.Value = serachParameter;

    //this is the place where i am getting error
    var result = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<City>("EXEC USP_GET_CITY @SERACH", parameter).ToList();
    return result;
}

// This is the city class 
public partial class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

```sql
// stored procedure 
Create procedure [dbo].[USP_GET_CITY] 
  @SERACH VARCHAR(100)
AS 
BEGIN 
 SELECT CITYID,CITYNAME+' || ' + STA.STATENAME + ' || ' + CTRY.NAME AS 
   CityName,STA.StaeteId as StateId, 1 as IsActive 
         FROM CITY CTY
         LEFT JOIN [STATE] STA
         ON CTY.STATEID=STA.STAETEID
         LEFT JOIN [COUNTRY] CTRY
         ON CTRY.COUNTRYID=STA.COUNTRYID

         WHERE CTY.CITYNAME LIKE '%'+@SERACH+'%'
         OR   STA.STATENAME LIKE '%'+@SERACH+'%'
         OR   CTRY.NAME LIKE '%'+@SERACH+'%'
END
```

Comment: In *SQL Server* there is not any `Boolean` field type instead it is `bit` that stores `1` or `0` that uses for `Boolean` support.

Comment: thanks  Gilad Green for advising me for stored procedure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set model property to boolean in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446054/set-model-property-to-boolean-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @RahulSrivastava please, do not solve the error in your question. This will confuse any reader who will try to understand your question later. Marking an answer as "resolved", and/or upvote good answers is the usual way to go in Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: ok I will take care of it

Answer (score 2):

In your `SELECT`statement, change

```
1 as IsActive
```

to

```
CAST(1 AS BIT) as IsActive
```

or

```
CONVERT(BIT, 1) as IsActive
```

Otherwise the `1` is treated as an integer by default, which is not consistent with the declared type in your C# definition

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your stored procedure is returning the IsActive column as an integer, where your code is wanting to store it as a Boolean.
Check your db table definition to make sure that the column is defined as a bit too, and that your stored procedure is not doing some conversion on it to make it an integer.

Answer (score 0):

TSQL sound a little tricky here, actually, sql server doesn't have a properly bool data type, actually none rdms has because a bool is actually a integer with length of 1 bit

With that in mind a cast should help once it forces the length of this IsActive field, I think if you do this without casting slq server will treat this like a int32, so:

```
SELECT CITYID,CITYNAME+' || ' + STA.STATENAME + ' || ' + CTRY.NAME AS 
   CityName,STA.StaeteId as StateId, CAST(1 as bit) as IsActive
```

is option one, and the second one is changing how your code works to accept a int32 instead of a boolean type like:

```
public partial class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IsActive { get; set; }
}
```